# iOS application update system

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm new to iOS development. And i can't find an answer to a question how does application update system work. I want to write a game which will have a set of levels. Then i want to be able to add new levels to the game (after it was uploaded into app store). So my game should be updated. And i don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case you need to make any change in the code, you will need to prepare a new submission build with version number greater than the previous submitted one and then submit to app store through iTunes Connect. This will go through the Apple review process again.

Comment: Generally Apple took less time for the update. But yes, the process is little long. It may wait several days in review queue.

Comment: And if i use NSUserDefaults for storing progress data and user's configuration it will stay on user's device and i will be able to use it, yes?

Comment: As far as I know, an update does not remove user data unless the app is completely removed. But I am not 100% sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to update your code, say levels are stored as xml files, a database etc., you don't need to go through the store. You could simply check with some (= your) server whether there is updated content available and download that to the device.